# How to Increase the capacity of a textbox in google app maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have created a database for work for a report and am in need of some help. When I try to add comments to the textboxes it gives me an error saying there is too much data. I have tried to extent the textboxes and make them as big as possible as well as played around with the "Data Validation" to give it a large amount of max characters but none of those work. Is there some other way to increase the amount of text these text boxes can hold?

(PS. I am using the text area widget not the text box widget which is supposed to be bigger but neither works)

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust SQL type setting in advanced field settings:
[image: Field settings]

Comment: Perfect that worked, thank you! One more question, is it possible to have a google sheet linked to the database so that everytime a record is updated it is automatically updated in google sheets? Or can we only export the data by click? Thanks!

Comment: There is no such functionality out of the box, but you can implement it using Model Events (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/events) and Spreadsheet API (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app). Here is a sample to start from - https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/spreadsheet/.

Comment: Okay perfect! Thank you